# Receiving to few chars from asio::async_write

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am calling my server via TCP/IP. I am sending a couple of chars and want to receive an answer, that is send by my `acknowledge`-fct. But I only receive as many chars as I sent to the server.

```
constexpr int maxInputBufferLength{1024};

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;


struct session
   : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{

public: 
    session(tcp::socket socket)
        : socket_(std::move(socket))
    {
    }

    void start(){
        do_read();
    }

private:
    void do_read(){
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, maxInputBufferLength),
                [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)

        {
            command_t currentCommand{data_};
            if(currentCommand.commandStringVector.front()==driveCommand){
                acknowledge("driveCommand triggered by TCP");
            }
            ....

    }

    void acknowledge(std::string ackmessage){
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(ackmessage, maxInputBufferLength),
                [this, self, ackmessage](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
                {
                    std::cout << ackmessage <<"\n";
                    if(ec.value()){
                        std::cerr << ec.category().name() << ':' << ec.value() << "\n";
                    }
                });
    }

    char data_[maxInputBufferLength];

};
```

According to my little knowledge, my `acknowledge` function that calls `async_write` with its own `boost::asio::buffer` should send the whole buffer, which should contain `ackmessage` with a length of `maxInputBufferLength` which is a global `constexpr int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour, because you pass local variable into `buffer`. `buffer` is only wrapper for string, it can be treated as pair: pointer to data and size of data, it **doesn't make copy** of `ackmessage`. You need to ensure that `ackmessage` exists until handler for `async_write` is called. `async_write` returns immediately, so what you have now looks like:

```
acknowledge ()
{
    ackmessage // local variable
    async_write is called, it creates buffer to askmessage, pointer to string is stored
    // async_write returns immediately
    // ackmesssage is destroyed here
}
```

Fix:

1) consider using synchronous writing operation

2) if you want to stay with *async* you could store `ackmessage` as data member of `session` and then pass it as argument to `buffer`. You need to find some way of extending its lifetime until handler is invoked.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861722/force-boostasiobuffer-to-copy-by-value) is nice example to resolve your issue, create `shared_ptr` from `ackmessage` and pass it to your handler - lambda, it extends lifetime of string which is being writing.